# How to use the output from sed command as a string and use that string in the grep command?

Tags: unix, sed, grep

I have a file with only one string per row, "File1", and a file that has two strings per row, "File2". I wan't go through File1 and check for every row/string in how many of the rows in File2 it appear.

I would like to use something like this:

```
grep '{sed -n 1p File1}' File2
```

But it doesn't work. Why and what should I do?

//Thanks!

Comment: `man grep`. The writers of `grep` have anticipated your need. `grep -Ff File1 File2` searchs for all text listed in File1 in File2 and produces output like `22 work` (count word). Good luck.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Ok, so I tried what you wrote, but ubuntu just outputs the whole file with red segments instead of counting the rows in File2 where an element from File1 appear. Both files are big, so I can't just count the red lines myself.

Comment: try `fgrep --color=none -f  <(sort file1) file2` (or check `man grep` for correct value to turn off color processing.) If you don't have `fgrep` then revert to `grep -Ff`.  If that doesn't work, then update you Q with a 5 lines of file1 and 10 lines of file2 with at least one match between the two. You need to understand what `grep -Ff listFile searchFile` can do, to be sure it will really answer your problem. `listFile` must(?) be sorted (that used to be true), OH and it has size constraints!. `man grep` and look for `LIMITS` Good luck.

Comment: Please add a [sample](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). You may not say it doesn't work without showing exactly what you consider to be working.

Comment: To answer the question in the title, use pipes: `sed -n 1p File1 | xargs -I{} grep {} File2`.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that you're asking two completely different questions: one in the title and one in the body. I'll try to summarize them and answer both.

**First question:**

How to use the output from sed command as a string and use that string in the grep command?

**First answer:**

The unix way is to pipe a command's output as input to another program. If you instead want to use the first program's output as e.g. a *parameter* to the subsequent command (not as its input), there's a handy program that allows you to do just that: `xargs`.

Example of piping the `sed` output as input to `grep`:

```
sed -n 1p File1 | grep 'needle'
```

Example of using the `sed` output as a search string for `grep`:

```
sed -n 1p File1 | xargs -I{} grep {} File2
```

**Second question:**

I have a file with only one string per row, "File1", and a file that has two strings per row, "File2". I wan't go through File1 and check for every row/string in how many of the rows in File2 it appear.

**Second answer:**

```
awk 'NR==FNR{!a[$0]++;next} $1 in a{a[$1]++} END{for(i in a){print i" "a[i]-1}}' File1 File2
```

Test files:

```
==> File1 <==
one
two
three

==> File2 <==
one apple
two bananas
two strawberries
three kiwis
three pomegrenades
three lychees
```

Test run output:

```
three 3
two 2
one 1
```

That's only if you mean the string from File1 to appear as the first column of File2. For a more general approach, where you want to count every File2 row containing the string from File1:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{!a[$0]++;next} {for(i in a){if(match($0,i)){a[i]++}}} END{for(i in a){print i" "a[i]-1}}' File1 File2
```

Test files:

```
==> File1 <==
one
two
three

==> File2 <==
one one
two one
two two
three three
three two
three one
```

Test run output:

```
three 3
two 3
one 3
```